# XNA.Texture2D to System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, xna, picturebox, texture2d

I need load XNA.Texture2D to PictureBox.

i've tried this: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=3224621 but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use that method, but make sure that your XNA Texture2D is created with a format of 32bbpARGB.  Any other format will prevent that method from working directly.

Comment: [Texture2D = bgr32]. but there is another problem, how could i 'reformat' texture to 32bbpARGB?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 4 * texture.Width * texture.Height; i += 4)
            {
                byte tmp = textureData[i + 0];
                textureData[i + 0] = textureData[i + 2];      //b  
                textureData[i + 2] = tmp;      //r
                textureData[i + 3] = 255;      //A
            }

it doesen't take too much time, but could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to do it is save the Texture2D using `Texture2D.SaveAsPng` or `Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg` to a memory stream and the open the virtual file using `Bitmap(Stream)`.