# Handling resizing over 100,000 uploaded images per day

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently we are resizing images in real time. Our users are uploading some 50K to 100K images per day. And our server is pegged at 100% cpu usage 24/7. And page load times are slow. **Ram is not an issue.**

We have a **Dual cpu intel xeon L5630 2.13GHz** server with **24 gigs** of ram. And we are using a simple image resize script to make the thumbnails from the original image. But this is maxing out the cpu's.

I'd like to attack this problem both via hardware and software.

- On the hardware side we are going to order another server with Dual Xeon 3GHz processors. This server will handle the image processing seperate from the website.
- On the software I'd like to ask someone with experience what kind of software they are using to process images with low cpu overhead.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: More hardware will resolve this, I don't think you should worry about the software if it's doing it's job.

Comment: I agree with the hardware part.

But if there is a library that can efficiently do the image resizing better than off the web script then it will save time.

Resizing 100 images is alot different than resizing 100K images per day. Even 1 second can make a difference.

Comment: This kind of transformation is something CUDA/ GPU programming does very well.

Comment: have you done a cost benefit analysis on utilizing amazon or google cpu's?

Comment: I'll look into GPU next. But we don't have a developer with experience in that sort of thing.

Comment: – Артём Царионов: That is something to look into. But we'd rather do things locally if possible. Might not be able to do this on an outside server.

Comment: Or Windows Azure, if you're a C# dev house. I'd be interested in your solution, we have a similar problem and I'm looking for a GPU-based command-line tool to do the grunt work.

Comment: -Luke Puplett I was looking into that as well. This thread here talks about image resize using XNA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130758/is-there-a-way-to-resize-an-image-using-gpu I'm not XNA developer so I don't know how well that will work but it seems promissing. However I think we are going to try with adding hardware and then possibly use ImageResizer to handle image resizing.

Comment: Flickr, Tumblr, and Pinterest all looked into GPU-based resizing, but it turns out CPU-based resizing scales better.

Answer (score 1):

#### First, analyze your read/write balance and (more importantly) read distribution

Most high-volume users discover that it's better to send uploads directly to blob storage, unmodified, and perform resizing dynamically on-request. There's a lot of benefits to this approach (agility, mobile support, control), but primarily it can reduce resource utilization. Most content never gets eyeballs; why waste resources on it?

#### Second, get a server-safe, server-optimized imaging library

It appears you're already looking at my software, [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net), which is the only server-friendly choice for .NET as far as I know. It also offers a range of pipelines, each with its own tradeoffs. **If you want raw speed, use the WIC pipeline; I expect you'll see 10-20x better performance than your current script.** The quality of the WIC pipeline isn't *quite* as good as the default pipeline, but it is 2-4x faster, and you won't be able to tell the difference on most images.

#### Consider getting help

I've assisted many companies in scaling past the 1 million and 10 million image barriers; there are a few architecture pitfalls to avoid, but at this scale it's good to take a very in-depth look at your needs. Is Varnish or a CDN an option? These can drastically help in scaling past the 500 image/sec barriers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've definitely have your software on the shortlist of options.

We did end up seperating the image processing function to it's own server. The server is a Dual Xeon X5680 @ 3.33GHz monster with some 96 GB of ram. The cpu usage on that box is just a few percent and handling the work of resizing a daily average of 44K images a day. And a Max day of 95K images.

In our case we need to create one thumbnail of the original image for insertion into a pdf report. I will kick around the idea dynamic image resizing with our lead dev. It seems reasonable to me.

And again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do they need to be processed in real-time? – If not you could look at a Queue bases system that utilities other servers / quiet time on the current server to process thumbnails.

Are the images only resized once, or is it possible for a user to request the image again causing another resize? – If so they you need to look at caching.

How large are the images being rezied and how many are being processed at once – if it’s spread out during the whole day?

Are the page load time delays caused by resizing the image during the postback? – if so they adding that instruction to a new thread would improve the response time.

Comment: Currently image resizing is done 24 hours a day practially. 
We have uploads from many users. Images must be resized so we can use them in documents.
We could use a queue. Images are under 5mb. And it's not so much page load but CPU usage at 100%

Comment: @Prescient Given that information a queue based system sounds the most logical.  You can also then monitor the queue, and if during peak times your queue gets too long for your own resources maybe start instances from a cloud based provider to temporarily add more resources rather than having more beefy hardware sitting redundant

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a good idea to separate image processing from the main server.

The best answer depends on more details from your particular situation : what software environment, what software used for resizing images, how it is configured, etc. It might be that optimizing there can yield a powerful speed improvement. For example, are there multiple cores, can GPU-based processing be used ?

That said, since every image resizing operation is independent from others, there is a generic solution. You can easily distribute the work on as many servers as you wish. Build one (or more if needed) extra image processing server. Then make so that resizing request are distributed. This can be done at several levels (Is resizing called by web clients via URL ? Randomize the server name in URLs you send to them. Is resizing called by business layer ? Randomize the server name there.).

If you need more specific answer, please provide more details.

Comment: Current setup is in the OP. But it's a 16 core Xeon fwiw.

And currently we are using asp.net 4 and C# to do the image resizing. With a basic resizing script we found on the web.

We have another dual multicore xeon 3ghz server on the way with a stupid amount of ram on it. Image processing will be done on that. 

What I'm really looking for is software that will handle image processing efficiently.

I'm looking at ImageResizer right now. It seems like it can do the job.

http://imageresizing.net